# How can I use STL to create a max and min heap for data points?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to solve a problem that leads me to create a max and min heap for some data points.  Suppose I have the following information:

```
(10,100)
(30,120)
(14,110)
(18,200)
(20,230)
(13,49)
```

And I want to store these data points in a max and min heap, but I want the heaps made by their second value.  However, I still need the first value preserved as I use it later in the program.  How can I accomplish this task?  What are the most efficient STL methods to always pop the max or always pop the min from a set of data points, while still preserving other, paired data?

Comment: What's wrong with set<pair<int, int>>?

Comment: @cubuspl42 How does this preserve the max- or min-heap invariant for only the second int in the pair?

Comment: To be clear, do you want a single min-max heap, where you can remove either the min element or the max element from the same data structure?  Or do you want a max heap, and also a [seperate] min heap?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Separate, but I'm most interested in the speed of the operations.

Comment: Do you only ever pop max or min or do you need to *add* elements after it's first initialized?

Comment: I definitely need to add elements and delete them (the max or min only) at various times.  In fact, this occurs quite often.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems straightforward:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> values = {
        {10,100},
        {30,120},
        {14,110},
        {18,200},
        {20,230},
        {13,49},
    };

    std::make_heap(values.begin(), values.end(), [](std::pair<int, int> const & lhs, std::pair<int, int> const & rhs) {
            return lhs.second < rhs.second;
            });

    // If you can't use c++11, then this is identical:
    struct {
        bool operator()(std::pair<int, int> lhs, std::pair<int, int> rhs) const {
            return lhs.second < rhs.second;
        }
    } Compare;

    std::make_heap(values.begin(), values.end(), Compare);

    // And if a priority queue works:
    std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>, decltype(Compare)> max_heap;
    max_heap.push(std::make_pair(10,100));
    max_heap.push(std::make_pair(30,120));
    max_heap.push(std::make_pair(14,110));
    max_heap.push(std::make_pair(18,200));
    max_heap.push(std::make_pair(20,230));
    max_heap.push(std::make_pair(13,49));
}
```

Comment: Suppose the vector had many more elements, would this be among the most efficient ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Also can you explain the syntax in the make_heap?  What does [](std::pair<int, int> const & lhs, std::pair<int, int> const & rhs) mean?  That is, where does the [] come from?

Comment: If the vector didn't have many more elements, I'd recommend just calling std::sort.

Comment: That syntax is a C++11 lambda. It can be replaced with a functor, which I'll give an example of.

Comment: Thanks.  The vector is actually many orders larger than this.  Should I use a set or map instead?

Comment: So is this one of the fastest ways to create a max/min heap if I'm continuously adding elements to the heap and continuously popping from the heap as well?

Comment: If you're only ever interested the max (or min) element, then you can use [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) instead of managing the heap yourself.

Comment: @sharth "std::set does not give you O(1) access to the largest value" `set::begin` and `set::end` are O(1).

Comment: @cubuspl42: Oops. You're correct about that. I was thinking that implementations had the option to use some sort of hashing, which would cause the container to not be sorted. I'm wrong about that though.

Comment: You're passing your comparison object as the template argument for `priority_queue`.  You need to be passing its class name.  Or use `decltype` if you don't want to give it a name. Then pass the object itself to the constructor.